# How a Security token service rely on asp.net application authenticated users to authenticate share point

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, claims-based-auth, security-token-service, claim-provider

i have a requirement to authenticate share point from an asp.net application, if an user is authenticated to asp.net and after that also  he able to authenticate to share point application .

in asp.net application there is one link **[viewbidata](http://#)** , if user click this page
he should redirect to share point and view bi pointers.

how i accomplish this scenario, here asp.net is farm based authentication enable, and it has  users in sqlserver and authenticate from sql server.

sharepoint web application is claims based authentication .

Here how i write a custom Security  token service and it must use asp.net application or rely on asp.net application authenticated users to authenticate sharepoint.

i want to authenticate sharepoint claims enable web application from an asp.net application which use farms based authentication.

I want to log in to a sharepoint site with the account or user its already authenticated in an asp.net application .

scenario:

1) an user login to an asp.net application( which is enable farm based authentication ) and this user validate from sql server and login successfully

2) after login successfully this user can see a link in Home page, that redirects to share point site(which is enable claims based authentication and in different domain than asp.net application )

3) and in this step Here i want ,this user automatically login to share point site ,

but without asking any authenticate page or login page.

here how i achieve this scenario when i create a custom sts service,?

Comment: how to write custom sts service to authenticate from asp.net to sharepoint